# Refresh/repaint issue with Eclipse ide 2018 under linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtk, linux-mint

I have repaint/refresh issues with my Eclipse IDE 2018 (under Linux Mint 18.3).

Indeed, stuff like this happen all the time:
[image: bug]

and I have to scroll or save to get the correct display:
[image: after refresh]

Before that, eclipse was very laggy/slow. I had to switch from GTK3 to GTK2. But this bug remains (still usable but annoying).

In my eclipse.ini

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

and in my eclipse configuration:

```
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gdk.backend=x11
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.theme=Mint-X
org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.version=2.24.30
org.eclipse.swt.internal.webkitgtk.version=2.4.11
```

Any idea?
Thanks